# Use fancybox to allow/prevent form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery, fancybox

Below is the jQuery I'm using to try and prevent/allow a form to be submitted once the user clicks the submit button. The idea will be to present a fancybox modal dialog window with the data the user entered for review. If they ,like, they click `Looks Good!` and the form is submitted back to the ASP MVC3 controller. If not, since the `e.preventDefault` method has already been called the modal window closes and they can re-enter the data.

The problem is, obviously as I have this written now, if the user is happy with the data they've entered, the whole thing will go into an infinite loop since I'm the `Look's Good!` button calls the method that displayed it in the first place.

Is there a way to create a "standalone" method inside the `submit()` function so I would have access to the event object and, if not, what would be a better way (i.e. actually works) to allow the form to submit after clicking the `Look's Good!` button?

```
    //Form submit functions
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#AccountNumber').val() != $('#doubleaccount').val()) {

            alert("Please re-enter the correct account number!");
        } else {
            var display = "<h1>Test</h1>" +
                          "<input type='button' value='Looks Good!' onclick='submit()'/>" +
                          "<input type='button' value='Try Again...' onclick='cancel()'/>";
            $.fancybox(display, {
                // fancybox API options
                fitToView: false,
                autoScale: true,
                autoDimension: true,
                closeClick: true,
                openEffect: 'fade',
                closeEffect: 'fade',
                closeBtn: true,
                openSpeed: 'fast',
                closeSpeed: 'fast'
            });
        }
    });
});//End doc.ready()

function submit() {
    $('form').submit();
}

function cancel() {
    $.fancybox.close();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest adding an attribute or setting a hidden value on the form with your first pass and then on the second pass, if that is set and they've clicked "Looks Good" you can submit it as normal via http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are preventing default, then you may need to `submit` the form via *ajax* to avoid the loop. I think this would do the trick :

```
function submitForm(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: "process.asp", // your controller
    data: jQuery("#myForm").serialize(), // serialize form with id="myForm"
    success: function(data){
      jQuery.fancybox("form successfully submitted"); // confirmation message
      jQuery('#myForm')[0].reset(); // clear form fields
    }
  });
}
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($('#AccountNumber').val() != $('#doubleaccount').val()) {
      // validation : something went wrong
      alert("Please re-enter the correct account number!");
    } else { 
      var display = "<h1>Test</h1>" +
                    "<input id='submit' type='button' value='Looks Good!'/>" +
                    "<input id='cancel' type='button' value='Try Again...'/>";
      $.fancybox(display,{
        // other API options
        afterShow: function(){
            $("#submit, #cancel").on("click", function(event){
              if( $(event.target).is("#submit") ){
                submitForm();
              }
              $.fancybox.close();
            });
        }
      }); // fancybox
    }
  }); // on submit
}); // ready
```

**Notice** that I added `ID`s to the `form` as well as the `buttons` to *submit* or *cancel* so I can bind events to all those selectors. Also notice that I used the `afterShow` callback to bind the `click` events in my buttons inside fancybox.

Useful to read : [Ajax serialize docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize)

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

**EDIT** : you could actually replace this line in your validation conditional

```
alert("Please re-enter the correct account number!");
```

by this one :

```
$.fancybox("Please re-enter the correct account number!");
```

so everything will look more consistent ;)